# Searching using Contains in SQL

Tags: sql, contains

I have a query using which I search data:

```
Declare @final varchar(20)
Declare @input varchar(50) = 'cat inot'

Set @final = '"*'+@input+'*"'

Select entry from tblentry where contains(entry,@final)
```

Here in entry column we have data as :'cat is not fruit'
Using Contains how can I modify my query to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product - and your code is non-standard SQL. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Try `like`. It works better.

Answer (score 0):

please try `containstablesearch`
first you need to enable fulltextsearch on desired table
then split and add `AND` stopword in between words

```
   Declare @final varchar(20)
    Declare @input varchar(50) = 'cat and is and not'

    Set @final = '"*'+@input+'*"'

    Select entry from tblentry CONTAINSTABLE(tblentry , entry , @final)
```

contains table search is better than like if data has more

Answer (score 0):

The `CHARINDEX` can help you as follow.

```
DECLARE @document varchar(64);  
SELECT @document = 'Reflectors are vital safety' +  
                   ' components of your bicycle.';  
SELECT CHARINDEX('bicycle', @document);
```